# How to get the length of a string into PCL of Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is the way to find the length of a string into PCL project? I can get the width and the height of a page for my device by using `Application` class, but I don't know how to get the measurement of a string.

P.S. I want to know could a user's device display full text or not.

Comment: `System.String` has a `Length' property, that is what you are looking for

Comment: do you mean the pixel count of a rendered string?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I had said about pixel size. I need to know can my device contains the given string into one screen page.

Comment: You would need to that in platform code, via DI or a custom renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be done for each platform on its own, you make a PCL interface like this:

```
public interface CalculateTextWidth
{
    double calculateWidth (string text);
}
```

and then for example on android the code will be like this:``public class CalculateTextWidth_Android : CalculateTextWidth
{
public CalculateTextWidth_Android () {}

```
    public double calculateWidth (string text)
    {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        TextView textView = new TextView(Forms.Context);
        textView.Paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);
        var length = bounds.Width();           
        return length / Resources.System.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity;
    }
```

see this link for more info and other platforms implementations
[how-to-get-the-length-of-a-string-into-pcl-of-xamarin-forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67545/how-to-calculate-or-measure-width-of-a-string)